# I want a burrito, but I have no avocado

Tags: substitutions, avocados

I am thinking of making a rice, salmon, and (chili) bean burrito, but I don't have any avocados.

After looking up some [substitutes](https://www.wellandgood.com/good-food/avocado-substitute/), I was thinking about peanut butter...but I am a little hesitant.

Has anyone tried to capture the texture of an avocado before?

Comment: What characteristics of avocado are you hoping to capture?

Comment: @Erica. Mainly the texture. Added to the question.

Comment: Your link is balancing things on some vague interpretation of "healthy" & ignoring anything else… like what it may taste like :\ Peanut butter on a burrito sounds … not good.

Comment: How about a bit of sour cream or cream cheese?

Comment: @Tetsujin, IMHO, I feel the same way about avacados. The sour cream or maybe some well-whipped cream cheese with chopped chives sound like a better option to me.

Comment: @Ring - tbh, I wouldn't dream of putting rice or salmon in a burrito either, but that wasn't the question. Avacado at least fits the 'Mexican' theme, I couldn't say the same for peanut butter, banana, pesto or hummus… & I don't even know what chia is. The link totally ignores taste or theme, it goes on some vague notion of 'health'.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I'm often amazed by some of the combinations I hear. The first time I'd heard someone ordering a pizza with pineapple on it, I thought they were deranged. I still do, but I figure as long as I'm not expected to partake, I don't care ;-)

Comment: @Ring - I'm definitely with you on the pizza/pineapple combo. Tried it once just to see… it was as gross as I imagined. Basil sorbet, on the other hand, which sounded equally 'weird' in my head, was a real eye-opener once tasted. I always say I'm prepared to try anything once… after that, let's see ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin, if you like chocolate and appreciate spicy hot foods, try chocolate brownies dipped in hot salsa!

Comment: I feel like we're being trolled here. Salmon bean burrito with peanut butter because there is no avocado? Is someone going to suggest toothpaste as a substitute next?

Comment: @Sobachatina No, I am actually that..."adventurous". It's not that I wanted that combination, but it's what I had on hand.

Comment: @ChrisHappy- I've been thinking about your question. Instead of trying to create a burrito and replace the avocado, if you think of the ingredients differently it might work better. If you made a fish taco with the salmon, you could make a thai sate sauce with the peanut butter. Refried beans and cheese wouldn't work there but whole black beans would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refried beans, or just skip the avocado?

Comment: Why are you asking him?